# How do i get this code to work? login/register program in python with dictionary and functions

Tags: python

```
login_input = {"MEK1300":"Python"}
username = {}
user = input("To login enter Yes. If you want to register enter No: ") 

def login_info():
  if user == "Yes":
    login_user() 
    
  else:
     user == "No"
     register_user()
     return user 
     
def register_user():
    new_user = input("Enter a username: ")
    if new_user in login_input:
        print("Your username already exists! ")
    else:
        new_password = input("Enter a password: ")
        username[new_user] = new_password 
        print("Successful registration!")
        
def login_user():
      login_user = input("Enter your username: ")
      password = input("Enter your password: ")
      if login_user in login_input and login_input[login_user] == password:
          print("Successful login! ")
      else:
          print("Invalid username/passord. Register a new user!")
```

This is the beginning of a multiple choice quiz in python btw. How can i make this work? I dont want it to be to complicated.

Comment: After taking the Yes, call your function by need.

Comment: What is your question here ? Where did you called your function `login_info()` your last line of code should be that. Also first step on login won't work `if login_user in login_input and login_input[login_user] == password:` wont work.

Comment: @R.Baraiya I think he is doing that in function `login_info():`

Comment: @AnelHodžić But havent call the beginning `Login_info()`

Comment: your code will not do anything ... you have to call the ```login_info()``` and your code will not give you what your looking for because of the  ```if login_user in login_input and login_input[login_user] == password:```

Answer (score 0):

I think youre code is fine you need to call you first fucnction to begin the quiz with `login_info()`

Updated code:

```
login_input = {"MEK1300":"Python"}
username = {}
user = input("To login enter Yes. If you want to register enter No: ") 

def login_info():
    if user.upper() == "YES":   #Convert YeS to YES 
        login_user() 
    else:
        register_user()
        return user 
     
def register_user():
    new_user = input("Enter a username: ")
    if new_user in login_input:
        print("Your username already exists! ")
    else:
        new_password = input("Enter a password: ")
        username[new_user] = new_password 
        print("Successful registration!")
        
def login_user():
    login_user = input("Enter your username: ")
    password = input("Enter your password: ")
    if login_user in login_input and login_input[login_user] == password:
          print("Successful login! ")
    else:
          print("Invalid username/passord. Register a new user!")
            
login_info()
```

Answer (score 0):

You did define a login_info() function but didn't really call it in the global scope. Also, the username dictionary wouldn't be persistent. After your first run, the username will be an empty dictionary again, so the register is not working. You can try saving the username dictionary as a JSON file and reading the file when you need to rerun it.